# Understanding date mismatch using timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, astropy

I have a dataset with time in days since 1-1-1 00:00:0.0 UTC, the last time is 736740.125 days.

It is indicated that the last date is Feb 14 2018 03:00 UTC.

Using astropy:

```
from astropy.time import Time,Timedelta
(Time('0001-01-01 00:00:00.0',format='iso')+TimeDelta(736740.125,format='jd')).iso
```

The output is `'2018-02-16 02:59:23.000'`

Also with Julian days:

```
Time(Time('0001-01-01 00:00:00',format='iso').jd+736740.125,format='jd').iso
Time('2018-02-14 03:00:00',format='iso').jd-Time('0001-01-01 00:00:00',format='iso').jd
```

The output is `'2018-02-16 03:00:00.000'` and `736738.125`

Similarly with datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime(2018,2,14,3)-datetime(1,1,1)
```

The output is `datetime.timedelta(736738, 10800)`, 736738.125 days

The dataset definitely has no data after the last indicated date of Feb 14 2018 03:00 UTC. I also have that same 2 days difference with the starting date, it is indicated to be Feb 20 2014 00:00 UTC, 735285.0 days since 1-1-1 00:00:0.0 UTC. However:

```
Time('2014-02-20 00:00:00',format='iso').jd-Time('0001-01-01 00:00:00',format='iso').jd
datetime(2014,2,20)-datetime(1,1,1)
```

Both give `735283.0` days

Does anyone understand where the 2 days difference might come from?

**EDIT:**

I get a match in IDL with the JULDAY function (https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/julday.html)

```
JULDAY(2,14,2018,3)-JULDAY(1,1,1,0)
```

Gives 736740.125

```
IDL > JULDAY(2,14,2018,3)
Python > Time('2018-02-14 03:00:0.0',format='iso').jd
```

both give 2458163.625

```
IDL > JULDAY(1,1,1,0)
Python > Time('0001-01-01 00:00:0.0',format='iso').jd
```

idl gives 1721423.5
python gives 1721425.5

I looked at differences for Jan 1 00:00 from year 1-2000 between JULDAY and Time().jd

Differences in days IDL-python

```
0 starting in 1583
10 for 1501-1582
9 for 1401-1500
8 for 1301-1400
etc for each 100 years
```

Thus for year 1-100 there is -2 days

I am not sure if there is an already existing way to replicate in python what IDL's JULDAY is doing.

Comment: I'm sure you understand that `1-1-1 00:00:0.0 UTC` is a fiction, as the calendar has changed drastically since 1AD, and was retrofitted from the modern system to the past? I bet there are a few special cases in that stitching of historical periods, needed to make the calendar match known dates in the distant past, that would explain the discrepancy. Try later dates, and find out when the first discrepancy occurs.

Comment: @9000 thanks, I think I figured what causes the difference. Will just need to figure out if there is already a python equivalent to IDL's JULDAY function.